# vim text width reformat

Tags: vim, text-width

I want to reformat my file so the max line width is 79. I did `:set tw=79` and `gggqG` and the results weren't what I expected. When a line is less than 79 col, characters from the line below it move up and lines with over 79 col don't break into two lines.

edit: Well I was semi-mistaken in that it DOES break lines over 79 except in the line with asterisks.

```
--CONVENTIONS**************************************************************************************
```

In addition it still moves characters up when the line has <79.

Comment: It works for me following your instructions, but check that lines are breakable. For example, urls will keep their original format after that width.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible solution, although not the best one.

Undefine `formatexpr` and let external `fold` program to format your text to 79 characters width.

```
:set formatexpr=
:set formatprg=fold\ -w\ 79
```

And now:

```
gg              # Go to beginning of file.
gq              # Format until...
G               # End of file.
```

And last remove those carriage returns (^M):

```
:%s/\r//g
```

In my test it changed some accented characters and some other lines were mangled, but try it yourself. Else you may write your own format function and use it with `formatexpr` option.

Comment: That worked although not perfect. Words got cut in half but that's not a huge deal.

Answer (score 1):

Put empty line between different paragraphs. Then do the reformat.

Comment: It doesn't send characters up a line when I add empty lines between each pair of lines however it doesn't actually split my longer lines into 79 col lines.